# Should I use 2 different Merchant IDs for testing & live in Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, flutter, applepay

I am integrating Apple Pay in my Flutter app (for iOS of course). Should I use a Merchant ID for testing environment and another one for live environment or I don't need to?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely separate, you should follow [the Apply Pay Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/) process/recommendations for testing to ensure you're never using your actual, live merchant ID.